# WordPress CSS stylesheet theme not recognized in FireFox

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web-deployment

My CSS stylesheet property like cta_ploha, cta_btn are nod displayed.

Link:

[Website](http://closetomyheart.q-tests.com/)

[CSS file](http://closetomyheart.q-tests.com/wp-content/themes/bst-master/style.css)

Can anyone help me with solving the problem?
I have declared .cta_ploha and included it, but id does not show up.

```
<link href="http://closetomyheart.q-tests.com/wp-content/themes/bst-master/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
```

CSS:

```
.cta_ploha{
background-color: #ebebeb;
border: 2px solid #ebebeb;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 2em;
margin-left: auto !important;
margin-right: auto !important;
margin-top:10%;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you run your style-sheet through a [CSS formatter](http://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/), you'll find the ploha-thingy is nested into

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .titlebar {
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
        .titlebar {
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .cta_ploha {
            background-color: #ebebeb;
```

So it would do it's style on a really tiny screen, got an Apple watch to test it? :)

It's always good practice to run CSS through a [CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator) - this one does not show the `.cta_ploha` rule which indicates it is hidden somehow.

Comment: A matter of seconds you were faster, haha, but this nesting stems from `inproper closure` as i mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS is not properly closed:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){.titlebar{padding-top:40px;padding-bottom:40px;}
@media screen and (max-width:320px){.titlebar{padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;}
```

This disables anything after it including `.cta_ploha`.

Comment: Yeah, was a tad bit later than Johannes.